# Trouble importing CSS file

Tags: html, css

I'm importing a style sheet and I don't know if it's my browser (MacBook/safari) or just not importing the right file.

#### new.html

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="new">

    hello
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

#### stylesheet.css

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.new {
  font-size: 42px;
}
```

Comment: i'm also on sublime text can't seem to set this up right, nothing pops up as error at all.

Comment: Where is your CSS file located? Is it in the same directory as `new.html`?

Comment: You are also missing an opening `<html>` tag. It needs to be before your opening `<head>` tag.

Comment: this is on a usb drive 2 different folders on the drive one folder <index> other <style>

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

Comment: should both individual files be in the same folder?

Answer (score 3):

You're referencing a stylesheet called `stylesheet.css`. As you don't specify a root-relative (`/`) or folder-relative (`./`) prefix, the stylesheet *must* be in the same folder as your HTML file.

As such, there's only four possible reasons for this problem:

- Your CSS file is not called `stylesheet.css`
- Your CSS file is not in the same folder as your HTML file
- You haven't actually **uploaded** your CSS file to the server
- Everything is working fine, and you simply don't realise, as you have cached the file

To ensure that you haven't cached the file, you can either:

- Perform a DOM refresh with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>
- Perform a CSS refresh with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Additionally, you've missed the opening `<html>` tag, which may be responsible for the stylesheet not loading, although your parser will almost certainly inject this tag for you automatically.

It sounds like you have the following structure:

- ROOT

  - index

    - index.html
  - style

    - stylesheet.css

As you say that your CSS file is in a folder called `style` which is a **sibling** of `index`, what you need to do is navigate up one folder with `../` and then explicitly reference the `style` folder:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

This states that the index file should look in the folder `style` (relative to itself) for the file `stylesheet.css`.

You can read more about file path transversal at **[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)**.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When referencing a CSS file, if it is in a different folder than your HTML file, the `<link ...` tag needs to include the correct path to this CSS file. Otherwise, just saying `stylesheet.css` assumes that they are both in the same folder.

In your case, your directory structure is (correct me if I've misunderstood):

```
- index
  -- new.html
- style
  -- stylesheet.css
```

So your `<link>` tag should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

`../style/stylesheet.css` means:

1. Go up one directory from the current (which is `index`)
2. Go to the directory named `style`
3. Find the file named `stylesheet.css`

Comment: so messing around with it i got the body background to change color but not the font size .new div to change to size of font

Comment: ANSWER WAS <DIV> NOT <DIV ="NEW">